# my ex employer sent me everyones hourly rates and salaries, can they get into trouble

Tags: salary

I would love for my ex employer to get a slap on the wrist for sending me everyones hourly rates and salaries. Can they get into trouble for this?

Comment: You might be able to get them under some privacy statute, but such cases are complex. This could also backfire badly on you.

Comment: Yes, just forward it back to every employee there on a Monday at 9 AM. I guarantee you that the employer won't like it. Where is this? You may want to consult with a lawyer first before you do that though.

Comment: Yes, they can get into trouble...question is, you want to be the troublemaker?

Comment: @Lehue Employment contracts are in the EU not considered (trade/company) secrets and you're allowed to freely discuss and share information that's in them, so long as it pertains to your employment.

Comment: @rkeet salary information of other employees indeed is a protected personal data: https://www.gdpreu.org/the-regulation/key-concepts/personal-data/ and you cannot give it to third parties (including other employees that have no necessity to know these data for their job)

Comment: @rkeet - If the laws are crafted to ensure government control over the industry, it is. The laws are ***obviously*** not necessary, yet they exist in Germany.

Comment: @Battle https://www.reuters.com/article/us-uber-court/german-court-bans-ubers-ride-hailing-services-in-germany-idUSKBN1YN171 banned for not adhering to laws pertaining transportation of passengers, has nothing to do with OP's question or being a dictatorship

Comment: @Lehue please find it on europa.eu for me to believe you and not one that has `Site powered by MailControl, which is not affiliated with the European Parliament or European Council` down the bottom in the footer.

Comment: @rkeet As the GDPR is a legal text, it does not lay out all details in an exhaustive list, but is subject to interpretation by courts. This means there is no such passus as "salary information is protected", but I'm pretty sure every court would rule that personal salary information together with employees names has to be protected so it is not shared with third parties by accident. I'm no lawyer, so feel free to search for a well-founded statement of a data protection specialist to prove your point.

Comment: @Lehue sorry mate, I'm going with "innocent until proven guilty" here ;-) Democratic country and all, I don't live in America where an accused has to prove innocence, but in a country (Netherlands) where an accuser has to provide the evidence.

Answer (score 4):

Taking legal or regulatory action against a company is a huge pain in the neck. It will probably take dozens of hours of your time. Ask yourself whether it's worth your trouble.

Your choices:

1. TIME-CONSUMING: go after them in some legalistic way.
2. NASTY: post the data anonymously on pastebin or otherwise "out" them.
3. POLITE: reply to the person who sent the mistaken data saying "I don't think you intended for me to get your message."
4. POLITE: delete the message and forget about it.

In my opinion, polite is always the way to go. It's a small world and people remember nasty behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it might feel good to send the info back to all the employees, to "punish" the employer, on the long run it will hurt you more or less. It is irrelevant if you love or if you hate the said employer.

The best thing to do is:

- remain professional;
- send a reply email to whoever sent you the information, telling them about the data leak; also ask them to be more careful about how they handle sensitive data in the future;
- it is not your job to judge or to punish anybody.

---

> Can they get into trouble for this?

Yes, and so can you. This might prove to be a complex problem, and you cannot predict how it might backfire.